# How to turn a var_export() into a serialized entry?

Tags: php, wordpress

So I've coded myself into a corner that I don't know how to get out of. I've got a series of arrays, each with two entries. A name, and an e-mail:

```
    array ( 0 => 'Crystal', 1 => 'Crystal@gmail.com', )
    array ( 0 => 'Tyler', 1 => 'Tyler@gmail.com', )
    array ( 0 => 'Richard', 1 => 'Richard@gmail.com', )
```

How can I turn each of these into serialized entries like this:

```
    $just_invited['name'];
    $just_invited['email'];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$serialized = array();
array_walk($arraySeries, function($val, $key) { global $serialized; $serialized['name'][]=$val[0]; $serialized['email'][]=$val[1];});
array_walk($serialized, function(&$val) {$val = serialize($val);});
```

Where `$arraySeries` is your array of names on key 0 and e-mails in key 1

$serialized now contains the serialized data of names and e-mails.

```
var_dump($serialized);
```

Comment: The only thing that's throwing me, is what variable `$arraySeries` is?

Comment: You said "I've got a series of arrays, each with two entries. A name, and an e-mail". I figured they were in the same array